# Update tvWidget in charting component using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tradingview-api

I am adding the tradingview charting library into my project and am having troubles getting the chart to re-render when I change the selected symbol.

When the chart loads initially it was calling a componentDidMount to submit parameters to their chart component which returns the chart. [This](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/) is the charting component and I have a list of securities beside it that update redux state for symbol when clicked.

what I want to do is force the chart to update when the state changes so the correct symbol is displayed.

It is the same issue mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022043/chart-update-in-tradingview-react-component-doesnt-work) question, but I'm using hooks instead of class based components and when I try to use useEffect as componentDidUpdate I am getting symbol undefined.

Update:: in other question they said to use something like this in componentDidUpdate

`this.tvWidget.chart().setSymbol('BINANCE:' + this.props.selectedSymbol.name)`

but I cannot figure out how to do something similar with hooks

charting.js

```
export function TVChartContainer(props) {
    const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState(props.symbol);
    const tvWidget = null;

    useEffect(() => {
        setSymbol(props.symbol)
    }, [props.symbol])

    const componentDidMount = () => {
        // setSymbol(props.symbol)
        const widgetOptions = {
            symbol: symbol,
            //symbol: 'BTC/USDT',
            //symbol: 'BTC/USD', //getUrlVars()["symbol"],
            datafeed: Datafeed,
            container_id: 'tv_chart_container',
            library_path: '/charting_library/',
            locale: getLanguageFromURL() || 'en',
            disabled_features: ['use_localstorage_for_settings'],
            enabled_features: ['study_templates'],
            charts_storage_url: props.chartsStorageUrl,
            charts_storage_api_version: props.chartsStorageApiVersion,
            fullscreen: false,
            autosize: true,
            width: '100%',
            timezone: 'America/New_York',
            client_id: 'Hubcap',
            user_id: 'public_user_id',
            auto_save_delay: 10,
            theme: 'Light',
            loading_screen: { backgroundColor: '#222222', foregroundColor: '#229712' },
            custom_indicators_getter: indicators,
        };

        const tvWidget = new widget(widgetOptions);
        // tvWidget = tvWidget;
        const thisComponent = props;

        tvWidget.onChartReady(() => {
            tvWidget.headerReady().then(() => {
                const button = tvWidget.createButton();
                button.setAttribute('title', 'Click to show a notification popup');
                button.classList.add('apply-common-tooltip');
                button.addEventListener('click', () =>
                    tvWidget.showNoticeDialog({
                        title: 'Notification',
                        body: 'TradingView Charting Library API works correctly',
                        callback: () => {
                            console.log('Noticed!');
                        },
                    })
                );

                button.innerHTML = '';
                // thisComponent.getPattern(); //might need to uncomment later

                tvWidget
                    .chart()
                    .onIntervalChanged()
                    .subscribe(null, function (interval, obj) {
                        console.log('On interval change');
                        thisComponent.getPattern();
                    });

                tvWidget
                    .chart()
                    .onSymbolChanged()
                    .subscribe(null, function (symbolData) {
                        console.log('Symbol change ' + symbolData);
                        // thisComponent.getPattern();
                    });

                // tvWidget.chart().createStudy('Strange Indicator', false, true);
                // tvWidget.chart().createStudy('ESS Indicator', false, true);
                // tvWidget.chart().createStudy('ESL Indicator', false, true);
                // tvWidget.chart().createStudy('EPS Indicator', false, true);
                // tvWidget.chart().createStudy('EPL Indicator', false, true);
                // tvWidget.chart().createStudy('ETS Indicator', false, true);
                // tvWidget.chart().createStudy('ETL Indicator', false, true);
            });
        });
    };



    const componentWillUnmount = () => {
        if (tvWidget !== null) {
            tvWidget.remove();
            tvWidget = null;
        }
    };

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     componentDidMount();
    //     // getPattern();
    //     // drawPattern();
    //     // // removeAllShape();
    //     return () => {
    //     componentWillUnmount();
    //     }
    // }, [symbol])

    useEffect(() => {
        setSymbol(props.symbol)
        componentDidMount();
        // getPattern();
        // drawPattern();
        // // removeAllShape();
        return () => {
        componentWillUnmount();
        }
    }, []);

    return <div id="tv_chart_container" className={'TVChartContainer'} />;
```

main page componenet

```
const TestPage = ({selected}) => {
    const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState('AAPL');

    useEffect(() => {
        setSymbol(selected)
    }, [selected])

    return (
        <div>
            <TVChartContainer symbol={symbol} />
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        selected: state.Watchlist.stock.selected,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestPage)
```

watchlist

```
const Security = ({index, name, stocks, selected}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [taskName, setTaskName] =useState(name)
    const [prevState, setPrevState] = useState(stocks)

    const removeTask = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        setPrevState(stocks)
        dispatch(removeStock(index))
    }    

    const selectAStock = () => {
        dispatch(stockSelected(name))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setPrevState(stocks)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(prevState !== stocks) dispatch(updateWatchlist(stocks, selected))
    }, [stocks])

    return (
        <Row className="list-group-item">
            <div className="item-titles" onClick={() => selectAStock()}>
                {name}
            </div>
            <button onClick={(e) => removeTask(e)} className="remove-item">
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </button>
        </Row>
    );

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        stocks: state.Watchlist.stock.watchlist,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {removeStock, updateWatchlist, stockSelected})(Security);
```

Comment: Where are you updating the symbol? In the main page components or in `charting.js`?

Comment: Added watchlist component, using a dispatch there to update symbol in redux state

Answer (score 1):

`this.tvWidget?.setSymbol("BINANCE", "5" as ResolutionString, () => null)`

The setSymbol accept 3 parameters:
`(symbol: string, interval: ResolutionString, callback: EmptyCallback): void`

- `symbol`: which is a string
- `interval`: which is of type ResolutionString. (`"5" as ResolutionString` use the 'as' to prevent error)
- `callback`: just an empty callback

on `componentDidUpdate()` you can update the tradingView Widget with the following parameters.